# How to create widget for start and stop voice recording

Tags: android, service, widget, using

In my project I have created a widget class, a service and a remote service, however I'm not able to 
call the methods for starting or stopping it. I've sample codes here

**For widget**

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, med_service.class);

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            Toast.makeText(context, pi.toString() + intent.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pi);
            Toast.makeText(context, pi.toString() + intent.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**for remote service**

```
public class service extends Service implements IBinder{

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("RemoteService", "onBind() called");
    return new RemoteServiceImpl();
  }
  /**
   * The IRemoteInterface is defined through IDL
   */


  public class RemoteServiceImpl extends IRemoteService.Stub {

    @Override
    public void start() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside start method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside stop method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  }
```

**for service**

```
public class med_service extends Service{

IRemoteService mService;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("RemoteService", "onBind() called");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service not bind to connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return new service();


}

class RemoteServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service ) {
                mService = IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            }
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                mService = null;
            }
    };

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    try{

            RemoteServiceConnection mConnection = new RemoteServiceConnection();
            getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(IRemoteService.class.getName()), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service not bind to connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            mService.start();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
}
```

any kind of help is appreciated

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

use getService instead of getActivity